# Actions not showing up on Lightning Activity component but they ARE on the layout

Tags: activities, lightning-app-builder, lightning-experience

I've been battling this one for longer than I would care to admit.  Currently I'm trying to get the Global Actions (Log a Call, New Task, Send an Email, etc) to show up at the top of the lightning experience "Activity" component.

I've searched all over and found the answer of "Add it to the layout" (which I did) and "Assign the relevant record type" (which I can't, because tasks don't HAVE record types so the option isn't in the Global Action).

I'm looking for another possible cause of this problem.  My org is a Developer edition scratch org, and I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Edit:  This is in relation to the Case object.  I have it working fine in a standard dev org, but my scratch dev org doesn't seem to want to show those buttons.

Comment: Are you talking about case object? If not, then what kind of object record page it is?

Comment: Added the detail to the original question but yes @sanketkumar it is the case object.

Answer (score 2):

On Case Record page in Lightning, The actions will appear in Chatter or chatter publisher component instead of Activities component. Make sure you are using Chatter or chatter publisher component.

Generally what happens in other object is:-

1. Chatter action appears into chatter or chatter publisher component
2. Activity actions like task, events etc. appears into activities component

but It works different for Case object.

In order to match the difference, What you can do is:-

Under the Activity Tab, Use two components together(Chatter publisher and Activites). See the pic below:-

[image]

Comment: I see that they show up in chatter, but I have another org where they're showing up clearly in "Activities" and I would rather use that UI than the chatter feed one.

Comment: @ScriptMonkey See the update in answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly the behavior changes based on whether or not you're using a feed-based layout.